# XMLWriter Not Found Using PHPWord

Tags: php, xml, phpword

I'm new to PHP and working on a project using PHPWord. But when executing the following code :
`$this->_xmlWriter = new XMLWriter();`
It said:

> Fatal error: Class 'XMLWriter' not found in .../PHPWord/Shared/XMLWriter.php on line 61

I checked PHP info using `php -m` and `php --rc xmlwriter`, then found `xmlwriter` module and its class has already been loaded.

Comment: Do you have the same problem when you create a simple test.php file with one line content **<?php $test = new XMLWriter(); ?>**

Comment: @PiKos Yes, the problem remains.

Comment: Ok, few more questions: 1) What OS do you use? 2) Are you doing all tests from command line or web server? 3) What version of PHP?

Comment: @PiKos I kicked the php request out of Ajax and the problem solved. thanks for advising:)